# How to create string of blanks (" ") in javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array that contains 10 elements, each element contains `" "`.

How do I create a string of spaces, like this:

```
"          "
```

in javascript or jQuery from the this array?

Thank you

Comment: There should be 10 blanks in the brackets, stack overflow has replaced it with a single blank.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want. Maybe show the result. You could use another character such as `_` to make it clearer.

Comment: @RoToRa - A `<pre>` block will do the job, I updated the question :)

Comment: @Nick: darn, I put a lot of effort into replacing those spaces with `&nbsp;`! ;-)

Comment: @Andy - Woops, didn't see you were editing as well..that'll teach you not to put any effort into improving questions!

Comment: @Nick True, but it's still easer to "read" or even count underscores than spaces :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would use [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/join) for this, like this:

```
var myArray = [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "];
var myString = myArray.join(''); //mySting is a string of 10 spaces
```

You need to pass the `''` to [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/join) because the default joiner is a comma.

Comment: Had a very basic syntax error, i was joining the array into a string and replacing blanks with  '', silly. Thank you very much!

Comment: @downvoter - It helps to say what is wrong, the question is he/she *already has* an array of 10 spaces and wants to join them.

Answer (score 24):

Easy, try it yourself in address box:

```
javascript:alert('“'+new Array(42).join(' ')+'”')
```

By the way, "in jquery" should be "using jquery"

Comment: +1 Nice one; this is the one-liner I was looking for! I had the number/length of string, but not the array yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try it with a `padEnd()` string method:

```js
let res = "".padEnd(10, " ");
console.log('start' + res + 'end');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use join for that.
Example:

```
var x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
var y = x.join('');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it with a `fill()` method:

```js
let res = Array(10).fill(' ').join('')
console.log('start' + res + 'end')
```